# Script hangs when assing get msol request to a variable

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I have done a script that create a folder structure in a sharepoint site.

Fisrt of all i created a backend script without a gui and it works great, it creates and modify folders as it must be.

Therefore i added a basic frontend with the System.Windows.Forms api. I added a form and some controls like buttons and labels and when i run the script it hangs. It connects to sharepoint online successfully but i realized  when invoke a cmdlet like get-SPOSite or get-SPOUser and i assig the return to a variable it hangs. Otherwise if i invoke a cmdlet like Connect-SPOService it works fine.
Main problem is that script hangs and no return any exception, it simply hangs and i have to close powershell ise. It seems problem is when have to asign the returned value to the variable. For instance in the first sentence wehere i have a pipe to filter results, if i debug i could see all returned sites, the get-SPOSite works but after the last result it hangs, never asign the value to the variable.

Somebody know what could be happens?

```
<# THis code works ok #>
 try{        
    Connect-SPOService -Url $adminUrl 
    return $True
}
catch{
    return $False
}
<# THis code Fail #>
try{        
    $siteExists = get-SPOSite | where{$_.url -eq $sitePath}
    <# or nextfail to #>
    $sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit All
    return $True
}
catch{
    return $False
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try(script won't run after return).

```
$result=$False
try{        
    Connect-SPOService -Url $adminUrl 
    $result=$True
}
catch{
    return $False
}    
try{        
    $siteExists = get-SPOSite | where{$_.url -eq $sitePath}        
    $sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit All
    $result=$True
}
catch{
    return $False
}
return $result
```